# Where is Kafka header for it's messages stored?

Tags: database, apache-kafka, header, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka headers to pass correlation id for Logging purpose, which is then used by Kafka interceptor to put in MDC. My question is where is the header information stored exactly, my postgres DB does not have any column for storing message header information, so where does kafka store this information? which datastore it uses?
Following are the column names of my kafka_message table. None of the columns store the header information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Headers are part of the record, as bytes, not a specific "datastore"

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#record

You'd need to check the code for this process you're using to write data to Postgres to see if headers are even "supported" since they are a relatively new feature to Kafka protocol